# Google Sign In on Android returning Error Code: 0

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My app has been published in the play store for about a year now and every thing was working fine. I have been working on a update and today when I tested , Google Sign In is not working for some reason. I changed absolutely nothing.

Here is the sign in code:

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
            private var googleSigninLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
    
            if(it.resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data)
                try {
                    // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                    account.idToken?.let {token->
                        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(token)
                    }
    
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                    Log.d("LOGIN_DEBUG", e.message.toString())
                }
            }else{
                utils.toast(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.there_was_an_error))
                Log.d("LOGIN_DEBUG", it.resultCode.toString())
            }
        }
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(Constants.DEFAULT_WEB_CLIENT_ID)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    google_signin.setOnClickListener {
            val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
            googleSigninLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
            utils.toast(this@MainActivity, resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
        }
}
}
```

I don't even know what to look for to find the issue.
I have re-checked all the credentials and everything seems to be correctly setup.
What could've happened?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your MD5 Keys once.If you are doing from other Machine you need to add your MD5 Key for the same.

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).